# Compiling a C# project as DLL for Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

As far as I know a C# project can be added to Unity3d in 2 forms. As DLL or uncompiled project.

What are the pros and cons of both? Will they work cross platform (Android/iOS/WinPhone)?

To compile as DLL - do I just use MonoDevelop or Visual Studio to new class library project and select .NET 3.5 and compile?

How do you add a uncompiled project to Unity3d?

Comment: Here's a handy quick start guide to doing that ... https://purplelilgirl.wordpress.com/2015/01/07/how-to-create-dlls-for-unity/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well Well Well too many question in a single post. Try to answer one by one:
Unity Offical Docs provide much help:

*Question*

**As far as I know a C# project can be added to Unity3d in 2 forms. As DLL or uncompiled project.
To compile as DLL - do I just use MonoDevelop or Visual Studio to new class library project and select .NET 3.5 and compile?**

> Usually, scripts are kept in a project as source files and compiled by
> Unity whenever the source changes. However, it is also possible to
> compile a script to a dynamically linked library (DLL) using an
> external compiler. The resulting DLL can then be added to the project
> and the classes it contains can be attached to objects just like
> normal scripts.
>
> It is generally much easier to work with scripts than DLLs in Unity.
> However, you may have access to third party Mono code which is
> supplied in the form of a DLL. When developing your own code, you may
> be able to use compilers not supported by Unity (F#, for example) by
> compiling the code to a DLL and adding it to your Unity project. Also,
> you may want to supply Unity code without the source (for an Asset
> Store product, say) and a DLL is an easy way to do this.
> [More](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UsingDLL.html)

**What are the pros and cons**

About dll:

Pros

- You can build DLLs separately.
- It could be faster to re-build one DLL

Cons

- Calling code from DLL is slower
- It would be slower to re-build hole project with all DLLs
- Function names are visible. It is easier to reverse code that uses
  dynamic DLLs
  You can find more on [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/38464/pros-and-cons-of-using-dlls), [here](http://blog.demigiant.com/unity-pros-and-cons-of-coding-into-dlls/) and specially on Google, our best friend:)

**How do you add a uncompiled project to Unity3d?**
Ans: What do you mean by uncompiled project? You mean scripts? then it is usually Copy\Paste inside asset folder simply.

Answer (score 2):

> Will they work Cross platform(Android/iOS/WinPhone)?

Yes. You can create a library project in Xamarin Studio/MonoDevelop/or Visual Studio. If you do not include platform-specific functions, it will be then cross platform.

> To compile as DLL - Do I just use MonoDevelop or Visual Studio to new class library project and select .NET 3.5 and compile?

See this [tutorial](https://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2015/12/09/packaing-unity3d-monobehaviour-script-into-dll/).

Comment: PCL are not supported in Unity.

Comment: PCL works great in Mono now. https://www.reddit.com/comments/1ofiyj/net_team_makes_portable_class_library_pcl/

Comment: Microsoft .NET PCL don't work with Unity because Unity is not built on MS .NET but Mono (which is portable by definition). Currently, Unity targets monos implementation of .net 2.0 (or a subset), which has its own implementation of core libraries (http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/compatibility/). You can read more here: http://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/05/20/the-future-of-scripting-in-unity/ . Your answer is simply misleading. Fix it and I'll remove the downvote.

Comment: Who said PCL is **Microsoft's**? If it is, how can it be called portable? Did you try using a PCL in Unity? If not, just do it. You seems not clear about PCL?! Best that you think carefully about if you have misunderstood it before downvoting. I laughed when seeing your links in the above comments.

Comment: You clearly don't understand what is PCL, it's microsofts portable implementation of their core .net libraries: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391%28v=vs.110%29.aspx 
It's hard to understand your intent but you probably think that anything 'portable' is a portable class library. Oh well, this argument goes nowhere. As a final note, create portable library project in visual studio and try referencing it in your main Unity project. Good luck.

Comment: @Bartosz, thanks for the link. Just noticed that .net 4.0 is the minimum target. You are correct! Updated the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Works perfectly, thnx! Used unity_2019.4.0, vs_2019 (16.10.1) with your recommended settings: .NET 3.5, file->new->project->"Class Library (.NET Framework) A project for creating a C# class library (.dll)". Reference to UnityEngine.dll is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

When you open your Unity project in an IDE (for example Visual Studio), it is a solution with two projects, one for game scripts and one for editor scripts. You can add more projects to the solution through your IDE of choice. In order for this to work, you need to set projects target framework to one that is compatible with Unity (which uses a subset of [Mono](http://docs.unity3d.com/410/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoCompatibility.html)), for example Unity 3.5 .net full Base Class Libraries. Unfortunately .NET PCL is not supported.

You can reference your (or third party) library in any of the projects as usual, just remember it also has to be compatible with Unity.

Wether your code will work on all the platforms actually depends on what you use. On platform specific limitations refer to http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformSpecific.html.

Comment: Unfortunately PCL is not supported. Any link to justify this?